# PowerShell Script to Change “Mappings to crawled properties”

Tags: powershell, managed-property, crawled-property

I want to change the “Mappings to crawled properties” from

```
Include content from all crawled properties
```

To

```
Include content from the first crawled property that is not empty, based on the specified order
```

for my couple of custom managed properties using PowerShell, What will be the possible powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SharePoint 2013 it would be:

```
$mp = GetEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Identity "YOUR MANAGED PROPERTY NAME" -SearchApplication "YOUR SEARCH APP NAME"
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Identity $mp -RespectPriority $true
```

You can reference TechNet here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608001.aspx

For SharePoint 2010 and a FAST for SharePoint SSA it is similar:

```
...
Set-FASTSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Name $mp -MergeCrawledProperties $false
```

You can reference TechNet here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393811(v=office.14).aspx